# How would I make a collider that stops the game when it collides with the "character"?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm still pretty new to this, so I don't know how to create a collider. My end goal is to have a game like the chrome dinosaur game. Same principles, and all. My question is, though, how do I even make a collider. I will be using a .gif for the "dinosaur". I'd like to make it where if this collider were to touch another collider, the game stops and a "game over" is shown. I have tried to create a collider, but they just keep showing up underneath the screen where the game is shown. Ant tips, tricks, or advice? Thanks

Code is as follows:

```js
let img; //background
var bgImg; //also the background
var x1 = 0;
var x2;

var scrollSpeed = 4; //how fast background is

let music; //for music

let catBus; //catbus

//collider variables
let tinyToto;
let tiniestToto;
let hin;
let totoWithBag;
let noFace;
let happySoot;

var mode; //determines whether the game has started

let gravity = 0.2; //jumping forces
let velocity = 0.1;
let upForce = 7;

let startY = 730; //where cat bus jumps from
let startX = 70;

let totoX = 900;
let totoY = 70;

let tinToX = 900;
let tinToY = 70;

var font1; //custom fonts
var font2;

p5.disableFriendlyErrors = true; //avoids errors

function preload() {
  bgImg = loadImage("backgwound.png"); //importing background

  music = loadSound("catbus theme song.mp3"); //importing music

  font1 = loadFont("Big Font.TTF");

  font2 = loadFont("Smaller Font.ttf");

  //tinyToto.setCollider("rectangle",0,25,75,75)
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000); //canvas size

  img = loadImage("backgwound.png"); //background in

  x2 = width;

  music.loop(); //loops the music

  catBus = {
    //coordinates for catbus
    x: startX,
    y: startY,
  };
  /*
  tinyToto = {
  x: totoX,
  y: totoY,
  }

  tinTo = {
  x : tinToX,
  y: tinToY,
  }
  */
  catGif = createImg("catgif.gif"); //creates catbus
  catGif.position(catBus.x, catBus.y); //creates position
  catGif.size(270, 100); //creates how big
  /*
  tinyToto = createImg("TinyToto.gif")
 tinyToto.position(tinyToto.x, tinyToto.y)
  tinyToto.size(270,100)

  tiniestTo = createImg("tiniest Toto.gif")
  tiniestTo.position(tinToX.x, tinToY.y)
  tiniestTo.size(270,100)
  */

  mode = 0; //game start
  textSize(50); //text size
}

function draw() {
  let time = frameCount; //start background loop

  image(img, 0 - time, 0);

  image(bgImg, x1, 2, width, height);
  image(bgImg, x2, 2, width, height);

  x1 -= scrollSpeed;
  x2 -= scrollSpeed;

  if (x1 <= -width) {
    x1 = width;
  }
  if (x2 <= -width) {
    x2 = width;
  } //end background loop

  fill(128 + sin(frameCount * 0.05) * 128); //text colour
  if (mode == 0) {
    textSize(20);
    textFont(font1);
    text("press SPACE to start the game!", 240, 500); //what text to type
  }

  fill("white");
  if (mode == 0) {
    textSize(35);
    textFont(font2);
    text("CATBUS BIZZARE ADVENTURE", 90, 450); //what text to type
  }

  catBus.y = catBus.y + velocity; //code for jumping
  velocity = velocity + gravity;

  if (catBus.y > startY) {
    velocity = 0;
    catBus.y = startY;
  }

  catGif.position(catBus.x, catBus.y);

  //setCollider("tinyToto")
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === 32 && velocity == 0) {
    //spacebar code
    mode = 1;
    velocity += -upForce;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey :) Cute game. Please improve and clean your code first; the code example you have doesn't actually have the targets rendered what to collide with. There also is some unnecessary variables and indentation issues and such ~~ :3 awso, you can easiwy wun this code hewe in a snipppet if you wemowe the fwonts, wemowe the backwound mufic and use placekitten.com fow youw spwites and fow the backwound :3

Answer (score 1):

well, this is how I would generally do that kind of thingy:

```
function draw(){
     for(let i in objects) // objects would be cactuses or birds
            if(objects[i].x > player.x &&
               objects[i].x < player.x + player.width &&
               objects[i].y > player.y &&
               objects[i].y < player.y + player.height){
            noLoop()
            // maybe do something else here
        } // you could also use: for(let object of objects)
     }
```

or if you want to do class stuff:

```
let player = new Player()

class Entity {

    hasCollided_pointRect(_x, _y, _width, _height){
        if(this.x > _x          &&
           this.x < _x + _width &&
           this.y > _y          &&
           this.y < _y + _height){
            return true
        }
    }
}

class Cactus extends Entity {
    
    update(){
        if(hasCollided_pointRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height))
            lossEvent()

    }
}

class Player {
    // ...
}

function lossEvent(){
    noLoop()
}
```

this is a pretty classy way to do it and for a small game you really don't need all of this

also MDN has a nice article on `rect with rect` & `point with rect` collisions,
`point with point` collision is just `(x == x && y == y)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

this is one of my recent loss "functions":

```
if(flag.health <= 0){
    noLoop()
    newSplashText("You lost!\nPress F5 to restart!", "center", "center", 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I handled game states in my Processing games was by making seperate classes for them. Then my main sketch's draw function looked something like

```
fun draw()
{
    currentState.draw();
}
```

Each gamestate then acted as their own sketches (for example a menu screen, playing, game over, etc), and had a reference to the main sketch which created the states. They would then alter the main's `currentState` to, i.e., a `new GameOverState()` etc. where needed.

For now, don't worry about doing that too much if all you want a really simple gameoverscreen with an image and some text.

I would suggest a structure like this instead. Use this pseudocode in your main draw function:

```
fun draw()
{
    if (gameOver)
    {
        // show game over screen
        img(gameOver);
        text("game over!");
        // skip rest of the function
        return;   
    }

    // normal game code goes here
    foo();
    bar();
    
    // update game over after this frame's game code completes
    gameOver = checkGameOver();
}
```

Now you need a way of checking for a collision to determine the result of `checkGameOver()`

For the collision handling, check out Jeffrey Thompson's [book/website on collision handling](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/rect-rect.php). It's an amazing resource, I highly recommend you check it out.

From the website I just linked, here's an excerpt from the website talking about handling collisions between 2d rectangles.

[image]

And here's a modified version of the collision handling function listed there (I updated the variable names to be a little more intuitive)

```
boolean rectRect(float rect1X, float rect1Y, float rect1Width, float rect1Height, float rect2X, float rect2Y, float rect2Width, float r2h)
{

    // are the sides of one rectangle touching the other?

    if (rect1X + rect1Width >= rect2X &&    // r1 right edge past r2 left
        rect1X <= rect2X + rect2Width &&    // r1 left edge past r2 right
        rect1Y + rect1Height >= rect2Y &&    // r1 top edge past r2 bottom
        rect1Y <= rect2Y + r2h)
    {    // r1 bottom edge past r2 top
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

You can use that function in your `checkGameOver()` function which would return a bool depending on whether your collision criteria are met.
For your game, you would loop over every obstacle in your game and check whether the dino and the obstacle overlap.

Pseudocode:

```
boolean checkGameOver()
{
    foreach (Obstacle obstacle in obstacles)
    { 
       if (rectRect(dino, obstacle))
       { 
          return true;
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```